# Начальная форма для "(ты) увяжешь"

Tags: глаголы, морфология

> Пожалеешь лычка, не *увяжешь* и
> ремешком.

Какая начальная форма для *(ты) увяжешь*? Это, вроде, [не *увязать*](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), иначе будет *(ты) увязаешь*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильно, увязать. Прочитайте внимательно информацию по своей ссылке. Есть два разных глагола "увязать".